# How to parallelize KMeans?

Tags: pyspark

I have a DataFrame with millions of rows. I have columns A, B and C. I have to cluster C over A and B.

For now what I'm doing is a `for` over every A and B set. Obviously it's slow, but I can't really parallelize it. I tried using Window and pandas_udf, but it doens't work with scalar functions.

Edit: some code to help understand my problem

```
# suppose we have a variable my_df which is a dataframe with millions of rows
# its schema is type, code, quantity
# I have to cluster quantity by types

# hundreds of types in real case
types = [1, 2, 3]

for index, t in enumerate(types):
    filtered_my_df = my_df.filter(my_df.type == t)
    # then I apply kmeans on filtered_my_df...
```

When I have hundres or even thousands of types, this code obviously is not scalable. But I can't figure out how to do this in scalable way.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Kmeans, it randomly selects k objects from the whole objects which represent initial cluster centers. Then, each remaining object is assigned to the cluster to which it is the most similar, based on the distance between the object and the cluster center. Then new mean for each cluster is calculated. This process iterates until the criterion function converges. This is why, it becomes very time costly.

You can use Parallel K-Means Based on MapReduce.

The distance computations between one object with the centers is irrelevant to the distance computations between other objects with the corresponding centers. distance computations between different objects with centers can be parallel executed.

MLlib implementation of k-means corresponds to the algorithm called K-Means\5 which is a parallel version of the original one. The method header is defined as follows: Let's say parseddata is you spark RDD.

```
KMeans.train(k, maxIterations, initializationMode, runs)

from pyspark.mllib.clustering import KMeans
clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, 2, maxIterations=10, runs=10, initializationMode='random')

# Evaluation

from math import sqrt

def error(point): 
    center = clusters.centers[clusters.predict(point)] 
    return sqrt(sum([x**2 for x in (point - center)]))

WSSSE = (parsedData.map(lambda point:error(point)).reduce(lambda x, y: x+y))
print('Within Set Sum of Squared Error = ' + str(WSSSE))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doens't really answer my question. But it's my fault, not yours. I'll add some code to help understand what I nedd.